# Syntax error, unexpected T_ENDIF

Tags: conditionals, ifelse, advanced-conditionals

I have the following code in my templates:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="cover" limit="5"}
    {if total_results > 1}More than one{/if}
        {covervid_bg_video limit="1"}{file:url}{/covervid_bg_video}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

And here is the error that I get:

```
Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ENDIF in 
/home/user34/public_html/dev/system/expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php(689) : eval()'d code on line 718
```

I tried the following variation with no success

```
    {if '{total_results}' > '1'}More than one{/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it did work it would output "more than one" 5 times.

I'd use count instead, like this:

```
{if count==2}More than one{/if}
```

There's [this](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/200648/) is interesting article over at ellislabs from some years back but still relevant.